# Audio Amplifier Clipping

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, audio, embedded, speakers

I designed a PCB with the following audio amplifier on it:
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/TFA9896_SDS-1381317.pdf

According to the data sheet, the amplifier is able to deliver 2.1W RMS into an 8 Ohm speaker at a battery voltage of 3.6V.

For testing the amplifier, I used a 3W speaker with 8 Ohm and played 16 bit wave files with a maximum amplitude of less than 1. When I play these files, there is strong clipping. This can be observed also for other speakers.

The audio amplifier boosts the input voltage to 6.1V and is able to provide a peak current of 2.5A. In my tests, I measure a peak current of 0.5A and an average current of 0.25A during playback.

As I'm lacking experience with audio amplifiers, I wonder how to fix this issue. When lowering the maximum amplitude of the wave files to less than 0.5, the clipping vanishes. However, I would like not to sacrifice for volume as the audio amplifier should be able to provide enough power according to the data sheet.

Comment: How are you measuring current?  Do you have an oscilloscope, and can you show us the waveforms at the speaker?

Comment: According to the datasheet, the amplifier has some kind off digitally controlled gain.  It doesn't go into details, but that's where I'd start looking

Comment: @Tim Wescott: I measure the current provided by the power supply. I'll check if I can get access to an oscilloscope.

Comment: @JRE: I checked it already, but unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Hermetica You need a peak to peak sinusoidal swing of \$11.6\:\text{V}\$ across \$8\:\Omega\$ to get an average output of \$2.1\:\text{W}\$. (It is pretty annoying to see "W RMS" in your question. For some reasoning why, see: [this wiki on RMS power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_power#Continuous_power_and_%22RMS_power%22).) Does this chip not only DC-DC convert, but then also operates the speaker in a bridged configuration?? That's the only hope of that kind of power from your supply rail. I may need to read the datasheet.

Comment: @jonk: Thanks for your answer. The "W RMS" is mentioned in the datasheet, too. As far as I know, the chip does only DC-DC convert.

Comment: @Hermetica Well, it is still annoying to see because it conflates ideas that shouldn't be conflated. Oh, well. So. Are you saying you don't think their chip provides two outputs so as to drive the speaker, bridged? I don't see how the stated power is possible, if not. When I get a moment, I need to read it myself, I guess. Until then, and maybe even then, I don't have anything constructive to add. So I'll stop at this point. Thanks so much for the response. It is appreciated.

Comment: @jonk: Thanks again. I was wrong as the chip supports bridged configuration.

Comment: @jonk: May I ask you one last question? You mentioned that a peak to peak voltage of 11.6 V across 8 Ohm is required to get an average output of 2.1 W. The datasheet says that the amplifier boosts the voltage to 6.1 V. However, shouldn't the peak to peak voltage be 12.2 V then? Here's a short fact sheet: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/fact-sheet/TFA9896FS.pdf

Comment: @Hermetica The equation is \$\pm\sqrt{2\cdot P\cdot R}\$ to get the voltage needed. But the IC also needs a little bit of voltage overhead for the switches. So that's probably why they DC to DC convert to 6.1 V. Bridged, this gets them enough to match the expression I just wrote.

Comment: @jonk: Thank you! Is it common that the power ratings of amplifiers found in there datasheets is only fulfilled for bridged configurations? I will pay more attention to that when looking for amplifiers next time as I wasn't aware that this could be the case.

Comment: @Hermetica Just use the expression I wrote out. If the supply rails are consistent with it, then bridging isn't needed. If the voltage rails are not consistent, then bridging or something other trick is required.

Comment: @Hermetica Even that may seem simple enough. But it assumes a nice sine wave. Real music tends to not look so nice, so a good rule is to figure that you want an amplifier that is rated about five times (Max or peak) of what you really think you need. So if you want about 2 Watts typically, then design to use voltage rails for 10 Watts. There are a lot of reasons why, distortion being one of them. But in general, good sounds result from some excess capability. It is a sad fact of life.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This answer is predicated on the fact that you can verify the clipping by putting a scope across the speaker.  And the clipping is happening near the 6.1V mark.

[image]

If the output of the amp is clipping, then you only have three choices,

1. Increase the voltage to the amplifier (if you can)
2. Reduce the gain of the amplifier if you can.
3. Reduce the amplitude of the input.

> I would like not to sacrifice for volume

After you do one (or more) of the above to regain audio quality, you can add more speakers in parallel, based on your output power description.  Two speakers should give you twice the output power 3dB(assuming that the amplifier drives them equally as well as it drives one speaker), then 4 speakers would double the output power of the two speakers to 6dB.

Turns out that for humans that 3dB changes in sound are marginally perceptible, 6dB is pretty noticeable and 10dB is considered double the volume (or half if going down).

[Doubling Power vs. Doubling Output](https://jlaudio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217201737-Doubling-Power-vs-Doubling-Output)

Thanks @ Marcus Müller for your comment.

Comment: you can't parallel speakers when your amplifier isn't designed to drive the higher load. This one doesn't seem to be! assuming infinite drive strength, i.e. modelling your amp as voltage source, you'd only get twice the output power with two parallel speakers – that's not twice the volume! Human perception is logarithmic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You're right, 10dB is a doubling of volume to a human. I'll update my answer.